# Как добавлять ребра в граф?

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть точки, мне нужно проверять коллизии между ними, решение было поместить все их в граф, весом будет расстояние между точками. При добавлении нужно как то проверять что ребро уже существует, как это правильно делать, может есть у кого то пример на любом Си подобном языке.
Нашел что то такое:

```
vector<int> graph[100000];    //массив из 100000 векторов.

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int u, v;
        cin >> u >> v;
        u--, v--;

        graph[u].push_back(v);
        graph[v].push_back(u);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int v: graph[i]) {    
            c++;                   
        }                          

        cout << c << " edges adjacent to vertex " << i + 1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Сделал так без графа:

```
namespace Helper {
    export class CollisionContainer {
        public container: Entities.GameEntity[] = [];

        public add(entity: Entities.GameEntity) {
            this.getLength(entity);
            this.container.push(entity);
        }

        public reset(){
            this.container = [];
        }

        public getLength(entity: Entities.GameEntity) {
            this.container.forEach((item: Entities.GameEntity)=> {
                let length = entity.position.getLengthToPoint(item.position);
                if (item.radius + entity.radius > length) {
                    item.onCollision(entity);
                    entity.onCollision(item);
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем проблема-то заключается? есть же граф, если ребро с двумя узлами есть, значит оно есть

Comment: Ответ скорее всего будет зависеть от того, каким конкретно образом Вы этот самый граф у себя храните. Если как список ребёр — это одно, если как матрицу смежности — это другое...

Comment: @Yaant, да вроде одинаково, что так, что так :)

Comment: @Yaant списки смежности

Comment: @Grundy, ну проверить значение элемента в двумерном массиве, зная оба индекса, всё же будет как-то попроще, чем искать нужный элемент в возможно неотсортированном списке пар вершин. :)

Comment: Если списки смежности, то в чем проблема-то? В самом простом виде - это булева матрица, в которой если `a[i][j] = true` и `a[j][i] = true` - то значит есть ребро между вершинами i j

Comment: @iksuy мне бы пример, а то с графами не работал толком

Comment: @iksuy, там не булевая, а числовая, _расстояние_ ж хранится, а не просто - можно достичь или нет

Comment: @Grundy а вообще есть смысл хранить в графе расстояния для проверки коллизий?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, а что ты понимаешь под коллизиями в данном случае?

Comment: @Grundy есть около 1000 объектов которые движутся в хаосе сталкиваются друг с другом, объекты имеют центр и радиус. При столкновении нужно менять вектор движения.

Comment: проще всего взять уже какой-нибудь существующий движок позволяющий это определять. Граф тут судя по всему не особо поможет, так как на каждом шаге нужно будет пересчитывать все расстояния для каждой из вершин.

Comment: @Grundy если взять box2d  то там много лишнего, а мне нужны только коллизии

Comment: @Grundy нашел что то такое https://github.com/jriecken/sat-js/blob/master/SAT.js